# Extraer los números diferentes de dos campos de int MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla y quiero comparar los id con los otro campo de la tabla ya que tiene relación a si misma

```
SELECT pers_id
FROM personas;
SELECT pers_padre
FROM personas;
```

En este caso quiero me traiga el 7

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para traducir tu pregunta, queres saber que datos de pers_id no estan en pers_padre?

Comment: Así es, es justo lo que busco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma de hacer esto en con la clausula [`in`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in)

Para ello, podes traer los registros que queres mostrar, solo si no estan en la otra consulta.

```
Select * 
from personas 
where pers_id not in (select pers_padre from personas)
```

Lo que hacemos en ese where, es decir que queremos que pers_id no este en la lista que se va a construir al seleccionar todo pers_padre.